How to get most recent globals variables everytime a function as ran
I'm creating a function that get a list of all the global dataframes in memory and does something with them. Example:
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

def func():
    # Get all dataframes in memory
    alldfs = [var for var in dir() if isinstance(eval(var), pd.core.frame.DataFrame)]
    
    # do something

    return dict(zip(tables_filtered, [ps.from_pandas(globals()[table]) for table in tables_filtered]))

func()  # returns df1 and df2

df3 = pd.DataFrame()

func()  # returns df1 and df2

The issue is that the global variables at the time of creation are stored and used everytime I run the function, but I want it to read the most up to date globals everytime its ran. So if 5 more dataframes are created after, it will return those.
Originally, I was trying to write the function in another module and import it, but the globals wasn't working so now doing it in the same notebook but having the same issue.
UPDATE
Okay to add more context since it seems like this is a bad approach. My goal was to pack the pyspark.sql feature into a function so that others using the notebook could easily just write sql queries on the dataframes:
def get_all_dataframes():
    return = [name for name,var in globals().items() if isinstance(var, pd.core.frame.DataFrame)]



def query_data(query):
    # Gather all dataframes saved in memory
    dataframes = get_all_dataframes()
    
    # Find all table names after FROM or JOIN
    tables = re.findall(r'FROM\s+(\w+)|JOIN\s+(\w+)', query, re.IGNORECASE)
    tables = [table for sublist in tables for table in sublist if table]

    tables_found = []
    # Check if tables exist in memory and replace them with curly brackets
    for table in tables:
        if table in dataframes:
            query = re.sub(r'\b' + table + r'\b', f'{{{table}}}', query)
            if table not in tables_found:
                tables_found.append(table)
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Table '{table}' does not exist in memory.")

    # Create the query args and turn Pandas DF into a Pyspark DF
    print(f"Tables detected: {tables_found}")
    query_args = dict(zip(tables_found, [ps.from_pandas(globals()[table]) for table in tables_found]))

    def _run_query(**query_args):
        return ps.sql(
            query, 
            **query_args
        ).to_pandas()

    query_results = _run_query(**query_args)
    print(f"Table created with {query_results.shape[0]:,} rows and {query_results.shape[1]:,} columns.")

    return query_results

So that way, instead of having to write this:
ps.sql('''
  SELECT m1.a, m2.b
  FROM {table1} m1 INNER JOIN {table2} m2
  ON m1.key = m2.key
  ORDER BY m1.a, m2.b''',
  table1=ps.from_pandas(table1),
  table2=ps.from_pandas(table2))

You can just write this:
run_query(
"""
SELECT m1.a, m2.b
  FROM table1 m1 INNER JOIN table2 m2
  ON m1.key = m2.key
  ORDER BY m1.a, m2.b
"""
)

This is a simple example. The queries are much more complex. And the reason for the sql is that I'm transitioning a lot of code to Python and a lot of the transformations were using PROC SQL (SAS). So in order for the end user to be able to make changes a bit easier.

Use globals() to get all global variables, not dir(). Then you don't need to use eval(), the value will be the value of the dictionary element.

You really shouldn't be writing code that depends on this in the first place, this sort of design is a huge problem waiting to happen.

This is a bad idea. Tying your code specifically to globals will be extremely limiting. It will cripple your ability to use basic programming tools like lists, modules, local variables, etc., as well as making it awkward to use globals that this function shouldn't care about.

What exactly are you trying to achieve? This seems like a very bad approach. If you explain what you're really looking for we might be able to give you a better approach. This looks like a XY problem.

What is tables_filtered? Is that supposed to be alldfs?

If you care about a particular set of data frames, at least make sure they are in an explicit list/dict/etc that you  maintain yourself. (That means you are responsible for adding them to the container, not just creating yet another global variable referencing new data frame whenever you feel like it.)

Thanks all for the comments. I added the function I created that I'm trying to get to work for more context. The idea is to simplify writing sql queries for users using the notebook that I'm creating to simplify it a bit.
Otherwise the code begins to look a lot like this: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.sql.html

Use globals()
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

def func():
    # Get all dataframes in memory
    alldfs = [name for name,var in globals().items() if isinstance(var, pd.core.frame.DataFrame)]

    # do something

    return alldfs

print(func())  # returns df1 and df2

df3 = pd.DataFrame()
print(func())

This outputs
$ python myfile.py
['df1', 'df2']
['df1', 'df2', 'df3']

This clearly contains df3, the newly created df, which is also in global scope
